# VSCode SSH auto-open terminal and run commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

I use VSCode with the `Remote - SSH` extension to connect to a remote dev enviroment.

During development on the remote machine, I use integrated terminal to view application logs. At this moment, I have to open new terminals and run commands manually, which is too much work for my lazy hands ;)

Questions are:

1. When I connect, I want VScode to open terminal tabs for me and run some commands (like `tail ./logs/whatever`). Is that possible?
2. If (1) is possible, can I also configure the terminals to open in VSCode `Split Terminal` mode?